# sorl-thumbnail generate different thumbnail on reload page

Tags: sorl-thumbnail

I have prepared the following template:

```
<a href="{{ articolo.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ articolo.nome }}">
        {# se c'è un'immagine o più le carico... #}
        {% if articolo.immagine_set.all|length > 0 %}
            {% thumbnail articolo.immagine_set.first.image "300x300" as im %}

                    <img
                        src="{% static "img/trans-214x300.gif" %}"
                        alt="{{ articolo.nome }}"
                        data-original="{{ im.url }}"
                        data-w="{{ im.width }}"
                        data-h="{{ im.height }}"
                        data-src="{{ im.url }}"
                        class="lazy{% if lazyOwl %}Owl{% endif %}"
                    />

            {% endthumbnail %}
        {# ...altrimenti carico quella di default #}
        {% else %}
            <img src="//placehold.it/215x300" alt="{{ articolo.nome }}">
        {% endif %}
    </a>
```

and I have installed sorl-thumbnail with django 1.6.5 and memcached

when reloading the page in a different browser, I get two different results, and then SORL does not retrieve the image from the cache.

```
<img
                        src="http://corestatic.fioretechnology.com/public/static/img/trans-214x300.gif"
                        alt="SCARPA BAMBINA PUMA"
                        data-original="http://corestatic.fioretechnology.com/public/media/cache/66/ab/66ab7d511792f550a4f5c239ec5e9118_137.jpg"
                        data-w="214"
                        data-h="300"
                        data-src="http://corestatic.fioretechnology.com/public/media/cache/66/ab/66ab7d511792f550a4f5c239ec5e9118_137.jpg"
                        class="lazy"
                    />
```

and:

```
<img
                        src="http://corestatic.fioretechnology.com/public/static/img/trans-214x300.gif"
                        alt="SCARPA BAMBINA PUMA"
                        data-original="http://corestatic.fioretechnology.com/public/media/cache/66/ab/66ab7d511792f550a4f5c239ec5e9118_136.jpg"
                        data-w="214"
                        data-h="300"
                        data-src="http://corestatic.fioretechnology.com/public/media/cache/66/ab/66ab7d511792f550a4f5c239ec5e9118_136.jpg"
                        class="lazy"
                    />
```

should not generate the same thumb?

how can I make him generate the same image?

thanks

also with this change:

```
<img
                            src="{% static "img/trans-214x300.gif" %}"
                            alt="{{ articolo.nome }}"
                            data-original="{% thumbnail articolo.immagine_set.first.image "300x300" %}"
                            data-hover="{% thumbnail articolo.immagine_set.all.1.image "300x300" %}"
                            data-src="{% thumbnail articolo.immagine_set.first.image "300x300" %}"
                            class="lazy{% if lazyOwl %}Owl{% endif %} flip"
                        />


<img
                            src="http://corestatic.fioretechnology.com/public/static/img/trans-214x300.gif"
                            alt="SCARPA BAMBINA PUMA"
                            data-original="http://corestatic.fioretechnology.com/public/media/cache/66/ab/66ab7d511792f550a4f5c239ec5e9118_141.jpg"
                            data-hover="http://corestatic.fioretechnology.com/public/media/cache/79/5b/795beef484ada8d8db9db02dd0e4f0b7_133.jpg"
                            data-src="http://corestatic.fioretechnology.com/public/media/cache/66/ab/66ab7d511792f550a4f5c239ec5e9118_142.jpg"
                            class="lazy flip"
                        />
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same or a at least a similar issue while playing around with sorl-thumbnail for the first time. Everytime i reloaded the page in the same browser or in another it resulted in regenerating the thumbnails.

This was caused due to Debugging still being enabled.

`TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True`

and results in filename */media/cache/7c/06/7c06aadd8e75768c4f92a76d6a6cc4a7_FRN3HDc.jpg*

After disabling it the random part in the filename after the underscore disappears and the file is loaded from the cache.

`TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False`

from now on the filename is */media/cache/7c/06/7c06aadd8e75768c4f92a76d6a6cc4a7.jpg*

Maybe this helps..